# Using void as syntactic sugar to guard against implicit globals, yes or no?

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntactic-sugar

I've been thinking about javascript programming style, and I was wondering whether it makes sense to add a bit of syntactic sugar to guard against the easily-made mistake of using an implicit global, i.e.:

```
var OuterFunction = function() { // closure container
    var renamedCounter = 0; // someone renamed counter,
    this.resetCounter = function () {
        counter = 0; // ... but forgot to check the inner functions as well.
        return this;
    };
    return this;
}
```

In this example, counter suddenly becomes a global variable, rather one that's
locally scoped to instances of `OuterFunction`.

By 'declaring' a closure-captured variable `void`, you get a free assertion, much
like any other code that uses `counter` without *assigning* to it.

```
this.resetCounter = function () {
    void counter; // this will throw an Error if counter is not in scope.
    counter = 0;
    return this;
};
```

**Edit**: as **jleedev** pointed out, just using the variable name itself seems to test whether
it exists, i.e.

```
this.resetCounter = function () {
    counter;
    counter = 0;
    return this;
};
```

will work just as well.

The advantages I see are these:

- It's short to write.
- It *looks* like a variable declaration, which it is, to an extent.
- **Edited to add**: If done consistently, it makes it very easy for a syntax checker (meat or program) to spot errors of this kind.

On the other hand:

- It's confusing.  The code doesn't actually *do* anything.
- Future interpreters may spot it as pointless, side-effectless code, and optimize it away.

Are there any aspects I'm overlooking?  Is this a dumb idea, or is it at least somewhat defensible?

**Question asker's Edit**: this should be a community wiki question, but I don't see a checkbox to change it to that.  I vaguely recall there being one.

**Edited for grand stupidity**: of course, `+=` tries to retrieve the value of the expression before incrementing.  So renamed the example to `resetCounter` rather than `incrementCounter` so that it makes a little sense.

Comment: I’m curious, is there a difference between `void counter;` and just `counter;`?

Comment: None that I'm aware of--just didn't realise it was syntactically valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ECMASCript Language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

> 11.4.2 The `void` Operator
>
> The production UnaryExpression : void
>   UnaryExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Call GetValue(expr).
> 3. Return undefined.
>
> NOTE GetValue must be called even though its value is not used because it may have observable side-effects.

So it should never be optimised away.

However it doesn't IMHO look remotely like "declaring" a variable, and certainly doesn't act like one, so should be avoided.

EDIT: indeed it shouldn't be used precisely because the GetValue call may have side effects, for example if the variable is actually a property with a 'getter' on it.

Comment: So, what would you recommend to guard against 'accidental' implicit globals?  Just the expression, as jleedev pointed out?

Comment: more attentive programming, "use strict" if you're on an EC5 compatible browser, or perhaps use something to record and periodically check for additions to the properties of the global window object during development.

Comment: 'more attentive programming' is not a solution, I'm afraid :).  But the strict mode answer is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is an answer to your question, but ECMAScript 5 [introduces the *strict mode*](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Annex_C), which prevents implicit global declarations:

> Assignment to an undeclared identifier or otherwise unresolvable reference does not create a property in the global object. When a simple assignment occurs within strict mode code, its *LeftHandSide* must not evaluate to an unresolvable Reference. If it does a **ReferenceError** exception is thrown ([8.7.2](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.7.2)). The LeftHandSide also may not be a reference to a data property with the attribute value {[[Writable]]:**false**}, to an accessor property with the attribute value {[[Set]]:**undefined**}, nor to a non-existent property of an object whose [[Extensible]] internal property has the value **false**. In these cases a **TypeError** exception is thrown ([11.13.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.13.1)).

In browsers that support it (which only seems to be Firefox 4 at the moment) you can activate the strict mode with

```
"use strict";
```

---

During development I use [**JSLint**](http://www.jslint.com/) to check my files for errors or problematic code. It notfies you about implied globals.